# SDSoC: Using only part of an array as sequential input in a function in HLS

Tags: vivado-hls

This question concerns the data movement in Xilinx SDSoC and HLS.

I have a large 1D array in my main function, which is being allocated using sds_alloc. It is basically a 2D array (of N rows and M columns) transformed into a 1D array of N*M elements.

I also have a function that accepts two arrays of size N as inputs, on the PL part.

I want this function to process two columns of the original 2D array - so, two parts of N elements stored sequentially in the 1D array, which has been allocated using sds_alloc in the main function.

Is there an efficient way to access these two parts of the array sequentially as a stream in the accelerated function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `sds_alloc` contiguosly allocates memory buffers and SDSoC infers DMA transfers over those buffers (that is what I assume you're aiming for).

I'm not entirely sure whether SDSoC is able infer *parallel* accesses to a "shared" array, but my gut feeling is that it can.

I'm sure you *can* call your hardware function over pointers poiting at different locations of the same array (*e.g.* an argument looking like: `&(x[i * N])`).

I would try something like this approach:

```cpp
void kernel(const data_t* col_1st,
            const data_t* col_2nd,
            // [...]
            ) {
    // [...]
}

// [...]

data_t* x = sds_alloc(sizeof(data_t) * N * M);

for (int i = 0; i < M; i = i + 2) {
    kernel(&(x[i * N]), &(x[(i + 1) * N]), ...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! I was also worried about whether SDSoC would have a problem with accessing the same array for 2 different inputs, but your intuition was right. Also, I couldn't figure out how this solution would work, since when you use a pointer you don't specify the size of the input array. This however can be done explicitly with: "#pragma SDS data copy(col_1st[0:col_size], col_2nd[0:col_size])" (or zero_copy accordingly).